# Issue with self join with a sub query;wanted to know the difference of 2 queries below

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

This working:

```
SELECT a.year, a.name, a.runs
from players a  JOIN
     (SELECT year, max(runs) runs FROM players GROUP BY year
     ) b  
     ON (a.year = b.year AND a.runs = b.runs);
```

This is not working:

```
select a.name,b.year,b.run
from players a join 
     (select year, max(runs) as run, name from players group by year
     ) b
     on a.year = b.year AND a.runs = b.run;
```

Can someone plz help me understand this?

Comment: add "name" to group by or use max(name ) in select

Comment: We have very little idea what you're doing/trying to do, so we can't really help. But in general, non-aggregated columns appearing in a SELECT clause also need to be included in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second  Join query  is not properly group by

```
     (select year, max(runs) as run, name from players group by year
 ) b
```

because you select also name  you should group by

```
        (select year, max(runs) as run, name from players group by year, name
 ) b
```

but this give you different result